# Is it good idea combine Meteor and AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, meteor

There are examples where Meteor and AngularJS are combined, but is it necessary?

Comment: If there were there any examples out there, their existence proves it was necessary.

Comment: If you know Angular, you can use Angular but you will have to find a way how to use Angular with Meteor. IMHO you don't need Angular. Meteor way is simpler and easier to learn.

Comment: I found answer> http://meteoric.github.io/ (... and I must be ironic: don't close question guys until you understand the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. You can make a project with one, the other or both. 
If you want a concrete answer, you should help us and tell what's the project or why you should (or not) use them both.

so it's not necessary to use both, but it can be usefull ...